# Center view in android after changing its width properties

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-linearlayout, gravity

I'm changing the width of a grid view based on its column width and number of columns (which works):

```
gridView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(gridManipulation.getColumnWidth() * (int)Math.sqrt(str.length) + 10, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
gridView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

I've tried re-centering it in the parent view but its not working, does anyone know why, its still centred as if it still has the width parameters before my dynamic change.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Gravity` as `LayoutParams` property then set that `LayoutParams` to your `GridView` as follows...

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(gridManipulation.getColumnWidth() * (int)Math.sqrt(str.length) + 10, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

gridView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: It's still in the top left corner!

Comment: try using `Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL` instead of `Gravity.CENTER`.

Answer (score 0):

you cant center it if its bigger than its parent, which is never bigger than the screen, unless you set it manually, which will cause the system to render data outside the screen and slow you way down.....

is it expanding verticaly or horizontally or both? my recomendation would be to put it in a scrollview.